# Como ordenar elementos do DOM pelo jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte lista:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Quero que todos elementos de números pares sejam ordenados, de maneira que fiquem os pares primeiro, e os ímpares, por último.

Assim:

```
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso via `jQuery`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depende um pouco como vais comparar os elementos. Usando o `index`, ou seja a posição deles poderias fazer assim:

```
var secundario = [];

$('ul li').each(function(i){
    if (i % 2 != 0) return;
    var removido = $(this).remove();
    secundario.push(removido);
});
$('ul').append(secundario);
```

Isso remove os elementos que não devem lá estar, guarda-os numa array à parte e no final volta a colocá-los. A parte `if (i % 2 != 0)` é para saber se o `i` é par ou ímpar. Caso a posição/index seja par não faz nada.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dt1b0nf/

Se quiseres usar o `.innertHTML` podes usar `var i = this.innerHTML;` (com `parseInt` seria ainda mais correto) e depois `if (i % 2 == 0) return;` assim: [(exemplo)](http://jsfiddle.net/7dt1b0nf/2/).

O mesmo código **sem jQuery** seria assim:

```
(function () {
    var secundarios = [];
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var lis = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
    [].forEach.call(lis, function (el, i) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) return;
        var removido = ul.removeChild(el);
        secundarios.push(removido);
    });
    [].forEach.call(secundarios, function (el) {
        ul.appendChild(el);
    });
})();
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dt1b0nf/5/

### Se fôr importante ordenar pode fazer-se assim:

> selecionar todos e iterar > separar em par/impar > ordenar cada um > juntar de novo no DOM.

JavaScript

```
(function () {
    function ordenar(a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.innerHTML, 10) > parseInt(b.innerHTML, 10);
    }

    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var lis = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
    var impares = [];
    var pares = [];
    [].forEach.call(lis, function (el) {
        var nr = parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10);
        if (nr % 2 == 0) pares.push(el);
        else impares.push(el);
        ul.removeChild(el);
    });
    [pares, impares].forEach(function (arr) {
        arr.sort(ordenar).forEach(function (el) {
            ul.appendChild(el);
        });
    });
})();
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/722w1dcg/

Comment: Quem deu o `-1` pode também comentar. Acho sempre bom trocar ideias e saber o que acham estar errado.

Comment: Todo mundo sofre um dia com o -1 fantasma.

Answer (score 2):

segue uma outra possibilidade, só que sem jQuery e tendo como base uma lista aleatória.

```js
var lista = document.querySelector("ul");
var itens = lista.querySelectorAll("li");

itens = [].slice.apply(itens);

//ordernar os itens de forma ascedente
itens.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {    
    return parseInt(itemA.innerHTML) > parseInt(itemB.innerHTML);
});

//ordernar os itens de forma a listar os numeros pares primeiro.
itens.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {    
    return parseInt(itemA.innerHTML) % 2 > parseInt(itemB.innerHTML) % 2;
});

//atualizar a ordem da lista 
//P.S: não há a necessidade de remover o elemento de forma previa.
itens.forEach(function (item) {   
    lista.appendChild(item);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>1</li>  
  <li>3</li>
  <li>7</li>  
  <li>2</li>  
  <li>6</li>  
  <li>9</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma que irá obter a ordenação que deseja:

```
$(function() {
    var elems = $('ul').children('li').remove();
        //ordena sua lista em ordem crescente
       elems.sort(function(a, b) {
         return (parseInt($(a).text()) > parseInt($(b).text()));
    })
       /* separa primeiro os pares em forma
          ordenada e mantém na sequência da lista os ímpares */
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        var numB = parseInt($(b).text());
        var numA = parseInt($(a).text());
         return (numB % 2 == 0 && (numB % 2 < numA % 2));
    });
    $('ul').append(elems);
});
```

Segue o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/jrHvf/67/

Comment: e eu ainda escuto gente dizer que usa jQuery para não poluir o código.

Comment: mas a pergunta pede que seja em JQuery. Não vejo poluição no meu código, está bem claro.